# Adobe Flash not working anymore with Browsers

Tags: windows-xp, flash, flash-player

I have a really annoying problem: essentially, Adobe Flash is not working anymore. For instance, I cant watch any clip on youtube and I always get a black screen saying:

Movie not loaded ...

I have the newest Flash version (10.0.45.2), and the problem is the same with IE, Firefox
or Chrome. I am using WIN XP and I turned of Antivirus software as well as Firewall, still
I cant watch any flash stuff.

Anyone an idea what could have happened in the last week? Never had a problem before that!

Thanks!

Comment: Try reinstalling Flash?

Comment: Lucky you! No more ads!

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall all Flash related items in your Add/Remove Programs list, then reinstall the latest version of Flash.

Answer (score 0):

Assueming you´re working at Windows, my first guess would be a Virus or some other malware...
I would do the following:

1. Turn Antivirus back on and scan system
2. scyn system with [Spybot](http://www.safer-networking.org/en/index.html)
3. look if some unnormal processes are running

Comment: thanks, i tried the suggestions, but I could not really resolve the issue. any other ideas?

THANKS